# Relative URL in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with running imgslider plugin. The sliding images can be loaded into a lightbox. There is a "load" and "close" buttons for the lightbox defined in a JS file. A plugin call is placed in each content.htm `imgslider('path to the img folder')`
The structure is about like this:

```
/content
    /2nd_lang
        content.htm
    content.htm
...
/plugins/imgslider/libs/lightbox/js/lightbox.js
```

In the lightbox.js, there is defined the path to the buttons img files

```
LightboxOptions = Object.extend({
    fileLoadingImage:        './plugins/imgcarousel/libs/lightbox/images/loading.gif',
    fileBottomNavCloseImage: './plugins/imgcarousel/libs//lightbox/images/close.gif',
```

This works fine on any content/page.htm. There are however 2nd_lang versions of the default pages and these are saved in /content/2nd_lang/page.htm. And there the images are not found by the script.
How shall the path be written to have it working both for default and 2nd_lang?

Comment: I guess that you should read about computer relative paths. It is like that for everything, not just JavaScript.

Comment: Thank for the hint. I have no problem to set paths in PHP. I just don't know how to define the paths in the `lightbox.js` so it would work both in `content/content.htm` and `/content/2ng_lang/content.htm`, which is of a deeper level. It makes no sense to adjust the js file for each webpage.

Comment: Oh, I see. Lets see if someone using lighbox has an answer.